# Traditional ASP.NET validators and mobile devices

Tags: asp.net, mobile, validation, smartphone

Currently I am thinking through a site that uses a responsive design to render nicely on smart phones etc.

I am in the habit of using the traditional ASP.NET validators for validation (e.g. RequiredFieldValidators etc) as I feel they do an ok job.

One question I have is whether the traditional ASP.NET validators work well in mobile devices with regard to their use of JavaScript or whether I should consider another mechanism

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "whether they work" then the answer would be "yes". It's just a javascript or, if the javascript is disabled, the validation is performed at the server side.

I think the only "challenge" is the small display of mobile devices - you should be careful about placing your validators so that they are clearly visible to users.